# Adding X.509 certificate to UEFI secure boot database?

Tags: uefi, nvidia-geforce, secure-boot, fedora-20

I have recently installed Fedora 20 on a custom desktop PC with a ASUS Z87-K motherboard. Given some commonly known bugs, I have installed the NVIDIA proprietary driver for my GeForce 630, and disabled the nouveau driver.

After completing correctly the driver installation, during which the module was signed with a newly generated key pair, a x.509 certificate was created and automatically placed in

`/usr/share/nvidia/certificate.der`.

However, from that moment, the computer is unable to boot  with the UEFI secure boot option enabled. When switching to textmode and running `nvidia-modprobe`, I find that the NVIDIA proprietary module was not loaded.

When I disable Secure Boot in the UEFI menu the computer boots and runs smoothly with the installed driver.

To avoid the drawback of booting in an insecure mode, I would like to know where to place the x.509 certificate of the NVIDIA module in order for it to be recognized by the kernel so I don't have to turn off Secure Boot.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to load the certificate using `MokManager.efi` so that it's recognized by Shim, and therefore accepted by the kernel. I don't know if Fedora sets its GRUB up so that you can launch `MokManager.efi` yourself. If not, try booting (with Secure Boot disabled) a USB flash drive with an EFI shell or [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) You should then be able to launch `MokManager.efi` and load the certificate file. (It will need to be stored on the same disk as the `MokManager.efi` utility -- probably `/boot/efi` from within Fedora.)

I'm pretty sure there's a way to add the certificate to the NVRAM from within Linux so that Shim will notice it and ask if it should be used the next time you reboot, but I don't know precisely what it is. Presumably it would involve writing the file to somewhere in the `/sys/firmware/efi` directory tree.

That said, I've never had to do this specific thing myself, since I don't use proprietary video drivers on any of my computers. It's conceivable there's some extra step you'll need to take.

Comment: Turns out you can use mokutil in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use mokutil to enroll the key.

```
sudo mokutil --import <der file>
```

You can test if a key is enrolled with

```
mokutil --test-key <der file>
```